# Doxygen XML-Output for C lang structs with sub-structs

Tags: c, xml, struct, doxygen

Structs with sub-structs are processed by doxygen as expected for output format HTML.

But for XML output format they are processed ambiguous as the following example shows.

**test.h**

```
typedef struct {
  struct {
    int   joe;
    short jack;
  } bar;
  struct {
    int   joe;
    short jack;
    long  bill;
  } saloon;
} a;

typedef struct {
  struct {
    int   joe;
    short jack;
  } bar;
  struct {
    int   joe;
    long  bill;
  } saloon;
} b;
```

**Doxyfile**

```
PROJECT_NAME           = Test
OPTIMIZE_OUTPUT_FOR_C  = YES
TYPEDEF_HIDES_STRUCT   = NO
EXTRACT_ALL            = YES
EXTRACT_LOCAL_CLASSES  = YES
FILE_PATTERNS          = *.h 
SOURCE_BROWSER         = NO
GENERATE_HTML          = YES
HTML_OUTPUT            = html
GENERATE_HTMLHELP      = NO
SERVER_BASED_SEARCH    = NO
GENERATE_LATEX         = NO
GENERATE_XML           = YES
XML_OUTPUT             = xml
```

The output files  **structa.xml** and  **structb.xml** are identical except *refid*-attributes and the stuct names themselves.

**Output of struct[a|b].xml** (*refid*s and struct names are replaced by "*", empty xml tags are cut out)

```
<doxygen xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="1.8.13" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="compound.xsd">
    <compounddef id="structa" kind="struct" language="C++" prot="public">
        <compoundname>a</compoundname>
        <includes local="no" refid="test_8h">test.h</includes>
        <sectiondef kind="public-attrib">
            <memberdef id="struct*_*" kind="variable" mutable="no" prot="public" static="no">
                <type>int</type>
                <definition>int a::joe</definition>
                <name>joe</name>
                <location bodyend="-1" bodyfile="test.h" bodystart="*" column="1" file="test.h" line="*" />
            </memberdef>
            <memberdef id="struct*_*" kind="variable" mutable="no" prot="public" static="no">
                <type>short</type>
                <definition>short a::jack</definition>
                <name>jack</name>
                <location bodyend="-1" bodyfile="test.h" bodystart="*" column="1" file="test.h" line="*" />
            </memberdef>
            <memberdef id="struct*_*" kind="variable" mutable="no" prot="public" static="no">
                <type>struct a::@0</type>
                <definition>struct a::@0  a::bar</definition>
                <location column="1" file="test.h" line="*" />
            </memberdef>
            <memberdef id="struct*_*" kind="variable" mutable="no" prot="public" static="no">
                <type>long</type>
                <definition>long a::bill</definition>
                <name>bill</name>
                <location bodyend="-1" bodyfile="test.h" bodystart="*" column="1" file="test.h" line="*" />
            </memberdef>
            <memberdef id="structa_1a4eec237b24903ad639c4f91aad9d8236" kind="variable" mutable="no" prot="public" static="no">
                <type>struct a::@1</type>
                <definition>struct a::@1  a::saloon</definition>
                <name>saloon</name>
                <location column="1" file="test.h" line="*" />
            </memberdef>
        </sectiondef>
    </compounddef>
</doxygen>
```

On parsing XML I am only able to recreate *a.bar* and *b.bar*.
But I can't say if *a.saloon* and *b.saloon* have only the member *bill* or *joe* and *bill* or *joe*, *jack* and *bill*.
This is a result that sub-structure *a.saloon* and *b.saloon* are different regarding member *jack*, but doxygen's XML output is identical for *a.saloon* and *b.saloon* .

Has anyone an idea to solve this problem for parsing XML (not parsing HTML instead of XML)?

Answer (score 0):

Would it be a solution for you to create non anonymous typedefs / structs i.e.

```
typedef struct A {
  struct BAR {
    int   joe;
    short jack;
  } bar;
  struct SALOON {
    int   joe;
    short jack;
    long  bill;
  } saloon;
} a;

typedef struct B {
  struct BAR {
    int   joe;
    short jack;
  } bar;
  struct SALOON {
    int   joe;
    long  bill;
  } saloon;
} b;
```

Comment: One can see similar problems when using HTML output where some comments / documentation flows to the wrong member and in the source code some members are not linked.

Comment: Yes, this works.
The original content of **test.h** is correct C code.
Doxygen should handle this -- so I guess this is a Bug.

Comment: Indeed it should be handled properly (I had a look yesterday but was not successful to find a solution), maybe you can submit a bug report in the doxygen issue tracker(https://github.com/doxygen/doxygen/issues/new)